# Como fazer localStorage.setItem('nomedoitem', 'valor') e fazer o 'nomedoitem' sempre mudar caso ja exista algum com o mesmo nome?

Tags: javascript

**Eu fiz um codigo onde ao clicar em um botao ele faz uma função que armazena um valor no promprio navegador, segue o exemplo abaixo:**

```
function favoritar(){
var SalvarURL = document.URL

localStorage.setItem('favorito', SalvarURL)
}
```

aqui ele simplesmente salva um "favorito" com a URL da pagina atual no armazenamento local do navegador.

Dai, eu queria fazer com que, se caso já existir um "favorito" ele crie outro "favorito" mas com o nome diferente, tipo... "favorito2" e se caso já existir o "favorito2" ele crie o "favorito3" e assim por diante. e se possível, caso já existir um "favorito" com a mesma url, ele negue e de um window.alert dizendo por exemplo que "Isso já está nos seus favoritos".

espero ter sido claro kkkk. quem puder me dizer se isso é possível ou não, e se for, puder me ajudar a fazer isso eu ia ficar muito grato, de coração mesmo <3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu espero ajudar na sua duvida. Vou tentar mostrar um solução, talvez complementar ou alternativa a do `@pedro_andrade`, a qual vamos criar um script manual e de maneira imperativa, ja que a API localStorage e simples e limitada (ou seja, não se iguala a de um banco de dados, mas nao leve isso como uma critica) para que possamos salvar de maneira incremental o `favorito` e pecorrer todas as chaves e verificar se a `URL` informada já existe.
Segue o script comentado para ajudar e tente executar para ver se ele funciona como voce deseja.
Obs: o código pode ficar mais limpo e modular, mas o que eu quero passar é a lógica.

```js
function favoritar() {
    // const salvarURL = document.URL;
    const salvarURL = document.querySelector('[name="url"]').value.trim();

    // vamos verificar se um ID ja existe
    let id = +localStorage.getItem('favId');

    // caso nao exista, entao assumimos que nao existe nada salvo
    if (!id) {
      id = 1; // valor inicial
      localStorage.setItem('favId', id); // salvamos o id no campo 'favId'
      localStorage.setItem(`favorito${id}`, salvarURL); // fica: favorito1

      return;
    }


    // o codigo seguinte server para verificar se a URL ja existe nos favoritos
    let urlExiste;

    for (let i = 1; i <= id; i++) {
      // se o favId for 5, vamos fazer um loop de 5 iteracoes e vamos comparar
      // cada uma das urls para verificar a igualdade

      const url = localStorage.getItem(`favorito${i}`); // favorito1, favorito2, favorito3...

      if (salvarURL === url) {
        urlExiste = true;
      }
    }

    // caso alguma url ja exista, alertamos ao usuario
    if (urlExiste) {
      window.alert('URL informada ja existe!');
      return;
    }

    // caso a url informada seja valida, salvamos ela e incrementamos o favId
    id = +id + 1;
    localStorage.setItem('favId', id);
    localStorage.setItem(`favorito${id}`, salvarURL);
  }
```

Agora vamos criar um `h2` com os favoritos e suas respectivas urls.
Vamos colocar uma `div` vazia no html com uma classe de nome `favoritos` onde serao exibidos os favoritos salvos no localStorage.
No html:

```html
<div class="favoritos">
</div>
```

Agora logo apos a linha do codigo **localStorage.setItem(`favorito${id}`, salvarURL)**, vamos adicionar a funcao `adicionaTituloFavoritos()` onde eu comentei para que fique explicado o funcionamento do codigo:

```js
    // ... 
    // invocamos a funcao toda vez que um favorito for adicionado.
    adicionaTituloFavoritos();

    function adicionaTituloFavoritos() {
      // selecionamos a div onde serao exibidos os h2
      const favoritos = document.querySelector('.favoritos'); 

      favoritos.innerHTML = ''; // damos um reset para limpar o 
                                // conteudo da div

      for (let i = 1; i <= id; i++) {
        const url = localStorage.getItem(`favorito${i}`);
 
        // se houver uma url, vamos criar um h2
        if (url) {
          const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
          h2.textContent = `favorito${i} - ${url}`; // texto do h2

          favoritos.appendChild(h2); // adicionamos a div dos favoritos
        }
      }
    }
```

Espero que meu codigo tenha ficado claro e tenha lhe ajudado.

Comment: Isso me ajudou MUITO! obrigado! 

Alem disso, eu tambem queria saber se tem como (concerteza tem) colocar todo "favoritoN" em algum h2, caso tenha 3 "favoritos" ele coloca 3 h2 com o nome do favorito que no caso seria "favorito1", "favorito2" e "favorito3", so exemplo ok.

Comment: tem sim, basta seguir a logica de realizar o loop e utilizar metodos do `document` para criar uma tag `h2` e inserir os favoritos e as urls. Se quiser posso acrescentar esse codigo na minha resposta.

Comment: Sim, please! isso iria me ajudar bastante e talvez ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo "problema" ou sla kkk.

Comment: adicionei, veja se minha explicacao lhe ajudou.

Comment: ok, vou testar aqui, qualquer coisa aviso aqui se funfou ou nao :)

Comment: Eu testei o codigo para adicionar em um h2 e uma parte do codigo está dando erro.


```
for (let i = 1; i <= id; i++) {
```

Essa parte do codigo, a parte de `<= id. i++`. No console diz que o "id" nao ta definido, e eu acho que e pelo fato do "id" ta dentro de outra função onde a variavel e um "let", (so to deduzindo) vc consegue me ajudar a resolver isso?

Comment: @3nder onde voce colocou a parte em que adiciona os `h2`? ele tem que ser colocado depois do `localStorage.setItem(`favorito${id}`, salvarURL);` e antes do fechamento da chave `}`

Comment: @3nder se quiver posso postar o codigo completo, pois nos meus testes funcionam normalmente. Acho que voce colocou a funcao `adicionaTituloFavoritos()` fora do escopo da funcao `favoritar()`

Comment: A, verdade. Analisei e foi exatamente isso, desculpa kkkkkk. Obrigado ae mano!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
function favoritar(url){
var SalvarURL = url;

var favorito = 'favorito';
var count = 1;

while(true){
    var itemJaExistente = localStorage.getItem(favorito); // caso esse item não exista, getItem retornará null
    if(!itemJaExistente) { 
        localStorage.setItem(favorito, SalvarURL);
        break;
    } else if (SalvarURL === itemJaExistente) { // verifique se o valor que você está tentando salvar já foi salvo antes
        alert("Essa url já foi salva!!");
        break;
    } else { // atualize o nome do seu item e continue o loop
        count++;
        favorito = 'favorito' + count;
    }
}}
```

A verificação de se essa URL já foi adicionada só funciona caso nenhum item seja removido do localStorage, pois assim, para se adicionar um item novo, deve-se percorrer todos os itens anteriores (do favorito até o favoritoN), podendo assim fazer essa verificação.

Uma outra maneira de resolver esse problema, talvez um pouco mais robusta, é guardar todas essas URLs dentro de um array no localStorage:

```
function favoritar(url){
var SalvarURL = url;

var favorito = 'favorito';
var urls = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('urls'));
if(!urls) { // crie o item caso ele ainda não exista
    urls = [];
}

if(urls.includes(url)) { // verifique se sua url já foi adicionada
    alert("Essa url já foi salva!!");
} else { // adicione a url
    urls.push(url);
}
localStorage.setItem('urls', JSON.stringify(urls)); // atualize o item no localStorage
}
```